# Trying to set ContentType for FormFile instance throws an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following simple method that creates a simple FormFile for testing.

```
    private static IFormFile CreateTemporaryFile(string fileName, string contentType)
    {

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test content");

        var formFile = new FormFile(
            baseStream: new MemoryStream(bytes),
            baseStreamOffset: 0,
            length: bytes.Length,
            name: "Data",
            fileName: fileName);

        formFile.ContentType = contentType;
        return formFile;
    }
```

It keeps throws a NullReference exception at this line `formFile.ContentType = contentType;`.
We have instance of the FormFile and ContentType is a public string property with getter and setter ? Am I missing anything  ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by the error and the fact that `formFile` clearly isn't null, it appears that `ContentType` itself is actually trying to access something that's null. From looking at the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/Http/Http/src/FormFile.cs#L48), that would appear to be the `Headers` property.

I believe you can initialize it like this:

```cs
private static IFormFile CreateTemporaryFile(string fileName, string contentType)
{

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test content");

    var formFile = new FormFile(
        baseStream: new MemoryStream(bytes),
        baseStreamOffset: 0,
        length: bytes.Length,
        name: "Data",
        fileName: fileName) 
    {
        Headers = new HeaderDictionary()
    };

    formFile.ContentType = contentType;
    return formFile;
}
```

Comment: oh good lawd. why MSFT ? Why ?

Comment: Yeah, it does seem like an odd one. I don't know if they don't expect other people to manually create one or what, but it's definitely odd.

Comment: Thank you DiplomacyNotWar , your change has fixed my unit test and VS is happy.

Comment: I think in most cases that would be provided by the framework, hence, not really expected to be filled in manually :)